# weakly convergence the sequence $f_{n}= n. \chi_{[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}]}$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

I need to research on the uniform, weak and strong convergence the sequence $$f_{n}= n. \chi_{[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}]}$$  for $n\in \mathbb{N},$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$  equipped with  norm $\parallel g\parallel= (\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g|^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}.$

...Intuitively I think

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0,
& \mbox{if $x\neq0$,}\\
\infty, & \ \mbox{if $x=0$.}
\end{cases}
$$

but not like working for example...

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|^{2}dx$$

I proffers do here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence does not converge with respect to the norm topology.The sequence is  not even bounded in norm, as $\|f_n\|^2=\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}n^2\;dx= 2 n.$

It also does not converge weakly. Otherwise $\int_R f_n(x)g(x)\;dx$ converges for each $g\in L^2(R).$ But this is not so. Example: Let $g(x)=x^{-1/3}$ for $x\in (0,1],$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x\not \in (0,1].$ Then $\int_Rg(x)^2\;dx= \int_0^1 x^{-2/3}\;dx =3<\infty, $ so $g\in L^2(R) .$ $$\text {But }\quad  \int_Rf_n(x)g(x)\;dx=\int_0^{1/n}n x^{-1/3}\;dx=n((3/2)(1/n)^{2/3} )=(3/2)n^{1/3}.$$